# Proving the linear combination of two solutions of a system of differential equations is also a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given a homogeneous set of differential equations: $$x^\prime = ax + by$$ $$y^\prime = cx + dy$$ I already know that two solutions of this system are $x_1, y_1$ and $x_2, y_2$, and I am asked to prove that $x_h = c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2, y_h = c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2$ is also a solution. Obviously we can prove this in a general case, but I was curious if we could solve this by direct substitution. I've already tried a few approaches but I'm just left with a jumbled mess of equations and a few relations that don't prove very useful. Could someone give me a hint as to how to approach this (this is in the first section of the chapter, so the solution to this problem does not use elimination, any matrix approach, etc.)?

Comment: @Chip Yes they are constants, and that is what the problem states. It gives two pairs of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{'}_h=ax_h+by_h \rightarrow (c_1x_1+c_2x_2)'=a(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)+b(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)$$
$$y^{'}_h=cx_h+dy_h \rightarrow (c_1y_1+c_2y_2)'=c(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)+d(c_1y_1+c_2y_2)$$
$$c_1x_1^{'}+c_2x_2^{'}=c_1(ax_1+by_1)+c_2(ax_2+by_2)$$
$$c_1y_1^{'}+c_2y_2^{'}=c_1(cx_1+dy_1)+c_2(cx_2+dy_2)$$
Subtracting the two equations we have:
$$c_1(x_1^{'}-y_1^{'})+c_2(x_2^{'}-y_2^{'})=c_1(ax_1+by_1-cx_1-dy_1)+c_2(ax_2+by_2-cx_2-dy_2)$$
$$c_1(x_1^{'}-y_1^{'}-(ax_1+by_1-cx_1+dy_1))=c_2(ax_2+by_2-cx_2-dy_2-(x_2^{'}-y_2^{'}))$$
Both the LHS and RHS in parenthesis are equal to zero therefore 0=0. And this is true for arbitrary values of $c_1$ & $c_2$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
x_h' &= c_1 x_1' + c_2 x_2' = c_1(a x_1 + b y_1) + c_2 (a x_2  + b y_2) = \\
&= a(c_1 x_1 + c_2 x_2) + b(c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2) = a x_h + b y_h
\end{align}
Do same trick for $y_h$ to get
$$
y_h = c x_h + d y_h
$$
which means, $x_h$ and $y_h$ satisfy same ODE you have for $x$ and $y$, therefore is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using a vector notation with:
$$
\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the system becomes:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \vec x=A\vec x
$$
and , for two solutions $\vec x_1$ and $\vec x_2$ we have:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} ( c_1 \vec x_1+c_2 \vec x_2 )=c_1\frac{d}{dt}\vec x_1 + c_2\frac{d}{dt} \vec x_2=c_1A \vec x_1 + c_2 A \vec x_2= A(c_1 \vec x_1 + c_2 \vec x_2)
$$
so $(c_1 \vec x_1 + c_2 \vec x_2)$ is a solution of the same equation.